# How can I convert pdf file into base64 in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I pick up the pdf file using file picker and I want to convert that file into base64 and save the converted base64 String to S3 Bucket?

Comment: Use [`File.readAsBytes`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/readAsBytes.html) to read the file as a list of bytes (`Uint8List`), and then call [`base64Encode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/base64Encode.html) on that list.

Answer (score 6):

```
import 'dart:io'

final bytes = File(pdf.path).readAsBytesSync();

String file64= base64Encode(bytes);
```

Pass the path of the File in pdf.path.